# Utterance reference for Google Smart Home in English and Western Europe languages

Tags: google-smart-home

I am developing a google smart home action app for interacting with our security systems. This includes also controlling relays for switches, outlets, lights, as well as thermostats for heating or cooling systems and some other peripherals, besides the original arming/disarming capabilities of the system.

Is there a place where I can find a sort of utterance reference (at least in English or in any Western Europe language)?

My company is Italian (as am I), and I am struggling to test the action (which is currently in DRAFT): most of the commands must be inferred by examples on the types & traits official documentation.

But this is far from being complete, plus it's in English only. Most of the times I'm trying to invoke the action using an Italian guessed translation from English examples but it's not working or understood by the assistant.

I also need to create a user manual for our customers in the available languages (I currently speak Italian and English only), and I need to give examples to the translators.

I cannot find anything anywhere.

Is there anything of the sort? Even a partial/incomplete list would do, to begin with.

Comment: I would recommend adding yourself to the cc list on the [open feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143807072) on the [public bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148). It helps raise awareness with the engineer teams as far as number of people requesting the new feature, and will allow you to be updated when updates occur.

Comment: Thank you @ToniCorinne for the suggestion, I've done it.

Answer (score 0):

Our internal team is constantly working on updating the public documentation for Smart Home devices with sample utterances for controlling  and interacting with them in the list of languages supported by the traits.

Right now we have provided utterances for devices in en-US, de-DE and fr-FR. More information about the sample utterances for Window (as an example) device type can be found here
https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/window#fr-fr

Meanwhile you can use Google Translate to convert phrases to other languages, and see if the translations are working for you.